# iOS MCBrowserViewController stuck on "Searching..."

Tags: ios, p2p, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to implement the iOS Multipeer Connectivity framework using the advertiser assistant and browser view controller. This seems simple, but the browser never finds my other device. Here's the code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCSession *peerSession;

- (void)startSession {
    MCPeerID *peerId = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];
    self.peerSession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerId];
    self.peerSession.delegate = self;

    MCAdvertiserAssistant *advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"myapp" discoveryInfo:nil session:self.peerSession];
    [advertiser start];
}

- (void)openBrowser {
    MCBrowserViewController *peerBrowser = [[MCBrowserViewController alloc] initWithServiceType:@"myapp" session:self.peerSession];
    peerBrowser.delegate = self;
    [self.appDelegate.mainViewController presentViewController:peerBrowser animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

This is running on two iOS 9.3 devices both with Bluetooth on, and connected to the same wi-fi network. The browser window opens but says "Searching..." and never shows the other device.

I tried running only the advertiser code on the device I'm trying to browse to. I also tried using MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceBrowser directly. Neither change made a difference.

I haven't found any web pages discussing this problem, so hopefully I'm missing something simple and obvious!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to hold a reference to your `MCAdvertiserAssistant`. It goes out of scope at the end of `startSession` and is being released.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MCAdvertiserAssistant *advertiser;

- (void)startSession {
    MCPeerID *peerId = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name]];
    self.peerSession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:peerId];
    self.peerSession.delegate = self;

    self.advertiser = [[MCAdvertiserAssistant alloc] initWithServiceType:@"myapp" discoveryInfo:nil session:self.peerSession];
    [self.advertiser start];
}
```

Comment: That was it! My thought was, I don't need a property because I don't need to access the advertiser later. But it makes sense that the advertiser would go away without this.